# Oracle - Comparing two columns with <>

Tags: oracle

I have the below WHERE Clause and I'm seeing results where the query is not returning data where the End_dt2 is blank

How can I return where the column does not equal with blanks?

The below value does not return.
Table:

```
id   End_dt    End_dt2  
1     1/1/15  

Where End_dt <> End_dt2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Null comparison always give problems. You should add a NVL to deal with that:

```
WHERE End_dt <> NVL(End_dt2, date '9999-12-31')
```

This of course, consider that when End_dt2 is null, the record should appear on your query.

Comment: You might try WHERE End_dt <> NVL(End_dt2, End_dt - 1) in case someone starts using a magical value for End_dt that coincides with your choice ... and maybe use Coalesce() rather than Nvl()

Answer (score 5):

If `end_dt2` is null then any comparison is undefined, but won't match. [Null behaviour is explained in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements005.htm#SQLRF51096). You could treat nulls as a magic date, but you can also check for nulls explicitly:

```
where end_dt2 is null or end_dt != end_dt2
```

If either column can be null and you want to treat one (but not both) being null as 'different' then you can do:

```
where (end_dt is not null and end_dt2 is null)
or (end_dt is null and and_dtl2 is not null)
or end_dt <> end_dt2
```